# Flexslider youtube clickable area

Tags: youtube, flexslider

I am using Flexslider 2 to create a simple playlist of youtube iFrames. I've gotten the code to pause youtube when changing slides and whatnot, but the big issue is the youtube control area. I think it stems from the FitVids.js making the iframe clickable area be jacked up. The odd thing is if I take FitVids.js out of the code, Flexslider 2 no longer works for iframes.

The clickable area is in the top left around 200px high and 400px across. The width of the video is 960px and whatever fitvids dems the height needed.

Here is the code I am using:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    function ready(player_id) {             
        var froogaloop = $f(player_id);             
        froogaloop.addEvent('play', function(data) {                
            jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider("pause");          
        });             

        froogaloop.addEvent('pause', function(data) {               
            jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider("play");           
        });         
    } 

    // Call fitVid before FlexSlider initializes, so the proper initial height can be retrieved.
        $(".flexslider").fitVids().flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            animationLoop: false,
            smoothHeight: true,
            slideshow: true,
            pauseOnHover:true,
            useCSS: false,
            video: true,
            before: function(slider){
                if (slider.slides.eq(slider.currentSlide).find('iframe').length !== 0)
                        $f( slider.slides.eq(slider.currentSlide).find('iframe').attr('id') ).api('pause');
                // ------------------  YOUTUBE FOR AUTOSLIDER ------------------
                playVideoAndPauseOthers($('.flexvid iframe')[0]);
            }
        });

    function playVideoAndPauseOthers(frame) {
        $('iframe').each(function(i) {
            var func = this === frame ? 'playVideo' : 'stopVideo';
                this.contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + func + '","args":""}', '*');
        });
    };

    // ------------------ PREV & NEXT BUTTON FOR FLEXSLIDER (YOUTUBE) ------------------
        $('.flex-next, .flex-prev').click(function() {
            playVideoAndPauseOthers($('.flexvid iframe')[0]);
    });


});
```

*EDIT*
I just found out everything works fine in Chrome but not Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer and it was totally un-related to anything here. I had an additional piece of jquery that was giving my iframes an additional class.

Basically the following CSS properties were screwing with the iframes. I use these on other objects when using transition effects because it gets rid of a graphic bug when using CSS3 transitions.

```
-moz-perspective: 1000;
-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-ms-perspective: 1000;
-ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
-o-perspective: 1000;
-o-backface-visibility: hidden;
perspective: 1000;
backface-visibility: hidden;
```